# Extract rows from a column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

hello am having data from 3 data-frames which i have merged i want to display first 3 questions per section for every candidate from status column,
here below i have merged data & subset the data to have desired columns

```
QDiff<-Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(A, B,C))

  Qdiff1<-subset(QDiff, select = c(candidate_id,status,question_id,section_id, diff_bucket))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Can you update with the expected output in your post so that it becomes more clear.

Comment: If you are grouping by `candidate_id` also, there are only 1 id that have 2 rows all others have only 1 observation.

Comment: I have doubt about the `section_id` and the `section` number in the `status` column.  Which one is the grouping variable.

Comment: Are you saying that there are three grouping variables i.e. candidate_id,section_id and the section number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is numeric values from 1:3, we can use that as index to replace it with the vector of `character`s in the same order.

```
Qdiff1$diff_bucket <- c('difficult', 'moderate', 'easy')[Qdiff1$diff_bucket]
```

If we need the first 3 questions for every section for each candidate

```
library(dplyr)
Qdiff1 %>%
      group_by(candidate_id, section_id) %>%
      slice(1:3)
```